# Python и mysql db

Tags: python, mysql

Всем привет, написал код, в котором открывается интерактивная консоль, в которую нужно будет вводить запросы MySQL, пока не будет введено 'Exit' и тогда программа закроется, но у меня проблема, не выполняются команды которые введены для запросов MySQL. Помогите найти причину и ее решение

вот Собственно код

```
import mysql.connector
import sys


def repeat():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='ace',
        passwd='1234'
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    x = input('Enter SQL > ')
    if x != 'exit':
        mycursor.execute(x)
        return repeat()
    else:
        print('Work with the database is complete')
        mydb.close()
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    repeat()
```

Comment: Почему вы думаете что команды не выполняются? У вас ведь нет обработки `mycursor.execute(x)`, например вывести результат

Comment: А как вы понимаете, что не выполняются команды? Меня лично смущает конструкция `return repeat()`, вы что ей хотите добиться? И наверное надо ещё как-то коммитить результат.

Comment: Ну ничего не выводится. Коммит добавил то, но ничего из за этого не изменилось. В выводе нужно что бы было. Добавил вывод через цикл выводить, вроде помогло, но я хз. Подожду, может кто даст еще какое то решение.

Comment: mycursor.execute(x) - выполняет команду на сервере, но не возвращает результат запроса. Для того, чтобы получить строки, возвращённые запросом, надо воспользоваться mycursor.fetchall(x)